# CasperJS: Access HTTP response status while downloading

Tags: csv, casperjs

This is about the [`download()` function](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) in CasperJS. I'm running CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3.

How do you access the HTTP status code in the response when downloading a file? In my code, some of the files I'm trying to `download()` are returning a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) response and I don't want to download these files. The actual HTML returned saying 'Forbidden' is being saved to the file rather than the expect CSV. (The files I'm trying to download should all be CSV files.)

Thanks!